# Multiple Thread modifying the same command attributes

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

**Problem Statement:-**

In my below program I am using `ThreadPoolExecutor` with an `ArrayBlockingQueue`.

Each thread needs to use an `UNIQUE ID` every time and it has to run for `60 minutes or more`, So in that `60 minutes` it is possible that all the `ID's will get finished` so I need to reuse those ID's again. So I am using `ArrayBlockingQueue` concept here.

Two Scenario:-

1. If the `command.getDataCriteria()` contains `Previous` then each
   thread always needs to use `UNIQUE ID between 1 and 1000` and
   release it for reusing again.
2. Else if the `command.getDataCriteria()` contains `New` then each
   thread always needs to use `UNIQUE ID between 2000 and 3000` and
   release it for reusing again.

**What Problem I am facing currently with the Below Program-**

> One problem that I am facing is

- In the `run method` if the `command.getDataCriteria()` is `Previous` then also it gets entered in the `else if block(which is for New)` which shouldn't be happening right? and also I am doing an `.equals check`? Why this is happening? May be because many threads will launch at same time and have modified the command before?

`else if(command.getDataCriteria().equals("New")) {`

If Multiple Thread is modifying it, then how I can overcome this problem? Whatever problem is happening it's happening in `run method`. Any suggestions will be of great help as I am stuck on this from a long time. May be we need to `Synchronize the threads, so that no other thread should modify the command when another thread is trying to execute it.`

```
public synchronized void runNextCommand() {

LinkedList<Integer> availableExistingIds = new LinkedList<Integer>();
LinkedList<Integer> availableNewIds = new LinkedList<Integer>();

executorService = new ThreadPoolExecutor(noOfThreads, noOfThreads, 500L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
        new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(noOfThreads), new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy());

    // If there are any free threads in the thread pool
    if (!(((ThreadPoolExecutor) executorService).getActiveCount() < noOfThreads))
    return;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
    availableExistingIds.add(i);
    }

    for (int n = 2000; n <= 3000; n++) {
    availableNewIds.add(n);
    }

    BlockingQueue<Integer> existIdPool = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(1000, false, availableExistingIds);
    BlockingQueue<Integer> newIdPool = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(1001, false, availableNewIds);

    // Running for particular duration of time
    while(System.currentTimeMillis() <= endTime) {
    Command nextCommand = getNextCommandToExecute();
    Task nextCommandExecutorRunnable = new Task(nextCommand, existIdPool, newIdPool);
    executorService.submit(nextCommandExecutorRunnable);
    }

    executorService.shutdown();
    if (!executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.DAYS)) {
    executorService.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

Implementation of runnable (the real unit level command executor)

```
private static final class Task implements Runnable {
private Command command;
private DPSclient m_DPSclient = null;
private DPSclient psc = null;
private BlockingQueue<Integer> existPool;
private BlockingQueue<Integer> newPool;
private int existId;
private int newId;
private static Object syncObject = new Object();  


public Task(Command command, BlockingQueue<Integer> pool1, BlockingQueue<Integer> pool2) {
    this.command = command;
    this.existPool = pool1;
    this.newPool = pool2;
}

public void run() {

  synchronized(syncObject) {
    if(command.getDataCriteria().equals("Previous")) {
    try {
        // Getting existing id from the existPool
        existId = existPool.take();
        attributeGetSetMethod(existId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        getLogger().log(LogLevel.ERROR, e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } finally {
        // And releasing that existing ID for re-use
        existPool.offer(existId);       
    }
} else if(command.getDataCriteria().equals("New")) {
     try {
        // Getting new id from the newPool
        newId = newPool.take();
        attributeGetSetMethod(newId);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        getLogger().log(LogLevel.ERROR, e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } finally {
        // And releasing that new ID for re-use
        newPool.offer(newId);   
    }
    }
}
  }
}
```

I will be appreciating your help into this. Thanks

**Update- Code for `getNextCommandToExecute method` as suggested by Matt**

```
// Get the next command to execute based on percentages
    private synchronized Command getNextCommandToExecute() {
    int commandWithMaxNegativeOffset = 0; // To initiate, assume the first one has the max negative offset
    if (totalExecuted != 0) {
        // Manipulate that who has max negative offset from its desired execution
        double executedPercentage = ((double)executedFrequency[commandWithMaxNegativeOffset] / (double)totalExecuted) * 100;
        double offsetOfCommandWithMaxNegative = executedPercentage - commands.get(commandWithMaxNegativeOffset).getExecutionPercentage();

        for (int j=1; j < commands.size(); j++) {
        double executedPercentageOfCurrentCommand = ((double)executedFrequency[j] / (double)totalExecuted) * 100;
        double offsetOfCurrentCommand = executedPercentageOfCurrentCommand - commands.get(j).getExecutionPercentage();

        if (offsetOfCurrentCommand < offsetOfCommandWithMaxNegative) {
            offsetOfCommandWithMaxNegative = offsetOfCurrentCommand;
            commandWithMaxNegativeOffset = j;
        }
        }
    }

    // Next command to execute is the one with max negative offset
    executedFrequency[commandWithMaxNegativeOffset] ++;
    totalExecuted ++;

    // This is for User Logging/No User Logging and Data is Previous/New
    LinkedHashMap<String, Double> dataCriteriaMap = (LinkedHashMap<String, Double>) sortByValue(commands.get(commandWithMaxNegativeOffset).getDataUsageCriteria());
    Set<Map.Entry<String, Double>> entriesData = dataCriteriaMap.entrySet();
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Double>> itData = entriesData.iterator();
    Map.Entry<String, Double> firstEntryData = itData.next();
    Map.Entry<String, Double> secondEntryData = itData.next();

    LinkedHashMap<Boolean, Double> userCriteriaMap = (LinkedHashMap<Boolean, Double>) sortByValue(commands.get(commandWithMaxNegativeOffset).getUserLoggingCriteria());
    Set<Map.Entry<Boolean, Double>> entriesUser = userCriteriaMap.entrySet();
    Iterator<Map.Entry<Boolean, Double>> itUser = entriesUser.iterator();
    Map.Entry<Boolean, Double> firstEntryUser = itUser.next();
    Map.Entry<Boolean, Double> secondEntryUser = itUser.next();

    double percent = r.nextDouble() * 100;

    if (percent < secondEntryData.getValue().doubleValue()) {
        commands.get(commandWithMaxNegativeOffset).setDataCriteria(secondEntryData.getKey());
    } else {
        commands.get(commandWithMaxNegativeOffset).setDataCriteria(firstEntryData.getKey());
    }

    if (percent < secondEntryUser.getValue().doubleValue()) {
        commands.get(commandWithMaxNegativeOffset).setUserLogging(secondEntryUser.getKey());
    } else { 
        commands.get(commandWithMaxNegativeOffset).setUserLogging(firstEntryUser.getKey());
    }

    return commands.get(commandWithMaxNegativeOffset);
    }
```

And commands has been declared at the top of the class as-

```
private static List<Command> commands;
```

**Update One More method:-**

```
private synchronized void attributeGetSetMethod(int id_range) {

        requestlTransaction requestlTransaction = null;
        try {
        GUID_VALUES = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();

        // I am not sure how CAL logging has to be done, it has to be at each attribute level or something else? So that is the reason I left this thing.

        if(!(command.getAttributeIDSet().isEmpty())) {

            requestlTransaction = requestlTransactionFactory.create("DPSLnPTest");
            m_DPSclient = setupDPS(command.getName(), getDPSAttributeKeys(command.getDataCriteria(), command.getUserLogging() , id_range));


            for(String attr: command.getAttributeIDSet()) {

            requestlTransaction.setName("DPSAttributeSet");
            requestlTransaction.setStatus("0");
            //requestlTransaction.addData("IpAddress", ipAddress);

            if(attr.contains("/")) {
                lengthOfString = Integer.parseInt(attr.split("/")[1]);
                attr = attr.split("/")[0];
            }
            DPSAttribute attr1 = new DPSAttribute();
            attr1.setRequestAttributeId(new DPSAttributeId(Integer.parseInt(attr)));
            DPSMetadataMgr mgr = DPSMetadataMgr.getInstance();
            DPSRequestAttributeMetadata metadata = mgr.getRequestAttributeMetadataById(Integer.parseInt(attr));
            int maxOccurs = metadata.getMaxOccurs();
            String dataType = metadata.getAttributeTypeAlias();

            DPSAttributeValue attrValue1 = getRequestAttribute(dataType, lengthOfString);

            if(maxOccurs>1) {
                DPSListAttributeValue listAttrValue = new DPSListAttributeValue();
                List<DPSAttributeValue> list = new ArrayList<DPSAttributeValue>();
                list.add(attrValue1);
                listAttrValue.setList(list);
                attr1.setRequestAttributeValue(listAttrValue);
                m_DPSclient.setDPSAttribute(attr1);
            } else {
                attr1.setRequestAttributeValue(attrValue1);         
                m_DPSclient.setDPSAttribute(attr1);
            }
            }

            List<DPSAttribute> idKeys = m_DPSclient.release(PersistenceEnum.COMMIT, false);

            // Iterating through the keys and storing into HashMap
            Iterator<DPSAttribute> i = idKeys.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
            DPSAttribute DPSAttribute = (DPSAttribute)(i.next());
            DPSAttributeId id = DPSAttribute.getAttributeId();
            DPSAttributeValue value = DPSAttribute.getRequestAttribute();

            if(id.getId() == DPSLnPConstants.CGUID_ID && (value)!= null) {
                DPSLnPConstants.CGUID_VALUE = ((DPSStringAttributeValue)value).getValue();
                GUID_VALUES.put(DPSLnPConstants.CGUID_ID, DPSLnPConstants.CGUID_VALUE);
            } else if(id.getId() == DPSLnPConstants.SGUID_ID && (value)!= null) {
                DPSLnPConstants.SGUID_VALUE = ((DPSStringAttributeValue)value).getValue();
                GUID_VALUES.put(DPSLnPConstants.SGUID_ID, DPSLnPConstants.SGUID_VALUE);
            } else if(id.getId() == DPSLnPConstants.PGUID_ID && (value)!= null) {
                DPSLnPConstants.PGUID_VALUE = ((DPSStringAttributeValue)value).getValue();
                GUID_VALUES.put(DPSLnPConstants.PGUID_ID, DPSLnPConstants.PGUID_VALUE);
            } else if(id.getId() == DPSLnPConstants.UID_ID && (value)!= null) {
                DPSLnPConstants.UID_VALUE = String.valueOf(((DPSLongAttributeValue)value).getValue());
                GUID_VALUES.put(DPSLnPConstants.UID_ID, DPSLnPConstants.UID_VALUE);
            } else if(id.getId() == DPSLnPConstants.SITE_ID && (value)!= null) {
                DPSLnPConstants.SITEID_VALUE = String.valueOf(((DPSIntAttributeValue)value).getValue());
                GUID_VALUES.put(DPSLnPConstants.SITE_ID, DPSLnPConstants.SITEID_VALUE);
            } else if(id.getId() == DPSLnPConstants.ALOC_ID && (value)!= null) {
                DPSLnPConstants.ALOC_VALUE = ((DPSStringAttributeValue)value).getValue();
                GUID_VALUES.put(DPSLnPConstants.ALOC_ID, DPSLnPConstants.ALOC_VALUE);
            } else if(id.getId() == DPSLnPConstants.ULOC_ID && (value)!= null) {
                DPSLnPConstants.ULOC_VALUE = ((DPSStringAttributeValue)value).getValue();
                GUID_VALUES.put(DPSLnPConstants.ULOC_ID, DPSLnPConstants.ULOC_VALUE);
            } else if(id.getId() == DPSLnPConstants.SLOC_ID && (value)!= null) {
                DPSLnPConstants.SLOC_VALUE = ((DPSStringAttributeValue)value).getValue();
                GUID_VALUES.put(DPSLnPConstants.SLOC_ID, DPSLnPConstants.SLOC_VALUE);
            } else if(id.getId() == DPSLnPConstants.PLOC_ID && (value)!= null) {
                DPSLnPConstants.PLOC_VALUE = ((DPSStringAttributeValue)value).getValue();
                GUID_VALUES.put(DPSLnPConstants.PLOC_ID, DPSLnPConstants.PLOC_VALUE);
            }
            }

            // Storing all the locators, guid in a map corresponding to an ID, then later on insert everything directly into db
            GUID_ID_MAPPING.put(id_range, GUID_VALUES);

            // Sleeping the command for particular milliseconds
            // One thing not sure, I should be sleeping the command here or I should put it above this comment line '// Iterating through the keys'
            Thread.sleep(command.getSleepTime());
        } 

        // for get attributes   
        // And also how CAL logging has to be done here too. And we can use same DPS Smart Client that got created above to get the attributes value?

        if(!(command.getAttributeIDGet().isEmpty())) {

            requestlTransaction.setName("DPSAttributeGet");
            requestlTransaction.setStatus("1");
            psc = setupDPS(command.getName(), getDPSAttributeKeys(command.getDataCriteria(), command.getUserLogging() , id_range));

            for(String attr: command.getAttributeIDGet()) {
            DPSAttribute attribute = new DPSAttribute();
            attribute = psc.getDPSAttribute(new DPSAttributeId(Integer.parseInt(attr)));
            //System.out.println(attribute.getAttributeId()+ " " +attribute.getRequestAttribute());
            }
        }
        } catch(Exception e) {
        getLogger().log(LogLevel.ERROR, e);
        } finally {
        requestlTransaction.completed();
        }

    }
```

Comment: If you post the code to the getNextCommandToExecute method it might be easier to figure out.  I don't see any big issue right off the bat (though i haven't delved too deeploy), but if you're re-using a command object that might have an impact.

Comment: Thanks Matt for the suggestion. I have updated the question with the code for `getNextCommandToExecute` method. Let me know if you need any thing else from me to figure out the right cause of the problem.

Comment: Are you expecting multiple threads to access the same instance of a `Command`?

Comment: @Brad, I don't need that I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see if `command.getDataCriteria()` is supposed to be accessed by only one Thread, then its' value shouldn't change due to threading synchronization issues. Assuming this we want to ensure that no two threads obtain a handle to an object instance.

You have `synchronized getNextCommandToExecute()` but there is no evidence of synchronizing your `commands` Collection based on your definition `private static List<Command> commands;`. If the assumption above is to hold we want to guranteee that no two threads can `get()` the same object instance from the Collection.

Where else in the code is the `commands` Collection being accessed from?

If `commands.get()` can be synchronized properly then there shouldn't be any thread contention on the instance returned. Which ever thread get's an object owns it.

...*feel free to tell me I'm barking up the wrong tree*

**[Edit]** following your comments

It is difficult for me to say for any certainty what's going wrong because I don't have all the code and there are assumptions to make. It looks to me like you're adding the `synchronized` keyword on many methods and expecting it to solve your problems. I think the best approach is to minimize the lines of code really need synchronizing and this will require a clearer understanding of what really needs to be synchronized.

1. You don't want to share references to a `Command` object across threads so make sure your get() and add() operations on `List<Command> commands` are synchronized. You could employ the use of a [synchronizedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29) or perhaps a [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)
2. Can you make the Command objects immutable? (i.e. no setX() methods)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So you are saying I need to synchronize `commands.get()` but already I have synchronized `getNextCommandToExecute` method, And how I can synchronize `commands.get` method?? Basically I am adding each `command attributes` to `commands` and I have declared this `commands` as `private static List<Command> commands;` at the top of the class? Do you need anything else from me in the code to indentify the root cause of the problem?

Comment: And command collection is also accessed from `attributeGetSetMethod` method in the `run method` and I have also made that `synchronized too`

Comment: In the `attributeGetSetMethod` I am only passing `some id`, So I need to pass the `command object also in that method`?

Comment: May be, I need to make this List `private static List<Command> commands` `thread safe`?

Comment: Thanks Brad for the detailed suggestion. Really Appreciated. Let me try those things first. Will update If I found anything fishhy..